# Eclipse with Phonegap. Android dev

Tags: eclipse

So I'm making an android app. I am using Eclipse. When I click on Window along the top and then click Android SDK and AVD Manager a little window pops up saying "Location of the android SDK has not been set up in the preferences". I looked this up and I needed to set the PATH variable. I did this but that little window still pops up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse menu->Window->Preferences->Android(on tree view on the left)->SDK Location on the right->Click Browse and point to your installation android-sdk folder.
This is in Eclipse Helios.

Comment: Al least tried my procedure? It should be the same.

Comment: android-sdk folder. when I open that after I click browse should I go to tools or a different folder?